# Why my Question is Downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I'm a newly active member here in Blender SE Network.

My Question - [Rock PBR Texture Creation within Blender (Procedural) for export in game engines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108760/rock-pbr-texture-creation-within-blender-procedural-for-export-in-game-engines)

here as Got -3 Downvotes.

As per the Guide to Ask Questions,

> **Search, and research**
>
> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone

As you can check my Question, it contains what I researched on the Tutorial of Andrew Price, other Youtube and even Substance Designer does. I've even put some of the effort to tell the users about the existence of different Species of rocks. A research on different types of rocks as well as different ways it's made in other Softwares. That's all that I've found on internet worth of explaining here.

> **Be on-topic**
>
> Our community is defined by a specific set of topics that you can view in the help center; please stick to those topics and avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion.

As you can see the whole Question is on explaining the users, what I want. I tried to explain different things. Although there are some discussions regarding Substance Designer because it was really required to mention that software the reference image was done with it and if someone wants how noises are mixed, then he can easily see substance Designer Timelapse in order to answer my question better.

> **Be specific**
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

I'm specific on the topic of what I'm trying to ask. I wrote everything in a chronological manner so that they can understand the question better. I'm specific to the blender and procedural materials, that's it

> **Make it relevant to others**
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.

You can see, I've added multiple images of different references, from different sources in order to make it relevant to others, I also asked the question in a manner, that others can understand what I want to know and What I don't. I've also added a Good Title for the summery of the whole text so that others can easily search the question if they need.

I've really put my efforts into the question by posting multiple images of what I want to do and not what so that others will not be confused. I've done maximum effort to keep my question on the topic and Interesting and also have added information about the content about the non-StackExchange website like blogs/tutorials/youtube and why they won't help me.

Also, additional efforts have been put to keep the question short, simple and meaningful.

So, why my question is downvoted? What's really wrong with me? I'm now banned too from asking questions. :(

Comment: It's hard to tell the reason why those who downvoted  left no comments. The best way to remedy a question that is not well received is to add additional information and to document your progress as part of the question. In this case you show what you want to do, but it might also help to show what you have tried and the results you are getting, even if they look strange or wrong. Then others might actually be able to give you concise and useful guideance.

Comment: You wrote .... [What's really wrong with me?]. What does that mean?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I thought people don't like me

Comment: While I didn't downvote I think question is a tutorial request which also asks for something like "stars and moon but not like those ones". E.g. quoting - "tutorials to create a procedural rock... are of no use here.. I want to create a rock surface" "not a rock, but a rock material [ ] which can be used to create more shapes of rock with different Maps". First one shows no research in tutorials because there won't be **one** tutorial about everything you want. Second is just unclear about what's your need. So for me downvote reason isn't unclear, note also there *is* a comment about reason.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha.  I asked the question to verify your intent and to see if you equate your BSE activity to [you entirety].  I assume people barely know you.  It seems you now have votes in the positive and the question has been turned around.  I definitely believe you have to kiss the fishy bass of certain others or someone will tell you your fish stinks.   Sometimes one gets unlucky and gets multiple negative votes when one would be sufficient.  So be it. I have plenty of negative votes.  Who cares?  Voters can be like piranhas.  Another BSE Tragedy becomes an inspirational juggernaut.

Answer (score 13):

I think I was the first to downvote the question and at that time immediately commented clarifying the vote.

> I downvoted this question, because it shows no research. I simple web search gives me plenty results and tutorials on procedural rocks in Blender and (Micro-)displacement. Do they not satisfy your needs? If not, why (illustrate)? There will be no perfect way applicable for every situation. Narrow down your field! (Games, Realtime, Still, Animation)

It still resembles a tutorial request more than a Q&A question, and I won't retract my downvote (yet), although you have 5/9 positive votes currently.

When I downvote I...

- don't dislike anyone on a personal level
- don't think the topic is uninteresting
- don't think your personal efforts don't deserve help

instead there simply will be one or two points which make it feel unsuitable for blender.stackexchange, as there are sets of hints for [asking good questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Yet, there are awesome downvoted q&a's like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79075/transforming-a-logo-into-birds/79098#79098) out of scope question, which I downvoted, but also had lots of fun writing an answer for. **But** the generated answer needs a lot of background knowledge to understand and may be not suited for a general audience seeking help.

I will point out what I (subjectively) think could be improved in your question. (Very nitpicky, and I understand that formulations are hard for us non-native speakers.)

#### Defining your topic

I can make out a block of bold text in your question, containing the question

> I wanted to ask if it's also possible to recreate Materials/Textures in Blender like Substance Designer?

If this is the main question it is out of scope, because it requires knowledge about substance painter. The additional information of *Substance Designer just mixes textures/noises/patterns to generate materials* doesn't resolve this issue. Since most procedural materials do that, we would still need to know about substance painter to recreate its effect/workings.

The second image gives me no additional information, remove it! The first image has displacement as well.

[image]

---

> There are many tutorials to create a procedural rock [...], but they are of no use here, because I want to create a rock surface.

Now, it may be difficult as you don't know the correct terminology, but did you actually follow one of those tutorials? Because, in almost every of those tutorials your going to learn about 
- modeling (meshes, geometry)
- maybe modifiers (subdivision, displacement)
- materials, textures and displacement

If you followed one of these turials you have created a procedural rock material which is independant of your geometry. You must explain why this method didn't help you! If you need the textures in another application they can't be exported as every engine has it's own equivalent for their procedural techniques. But you don't mention your specific goal. [The material is covered in many tutorials, I followed them.]

> Rock Surface = create Displacement, Albedo and Normal Map which is fully procedural [...]

This is important information and should be in the main question. **But** in what format do you need it? Blender material (can't be [tutorials, blabla]), image texture (can't be fully procedural)

This is my main problem with this question, which makes it unanswerable, because I don't know of a universal format for materials which contain procedural textures.

... if it wasn't for

> and please share the .blend file

Ok, so you want a .blend file with a material. This is vital information and should be in the question, not just as an optional piece of the answer.

> I want the recreation of Displacement/Normal/Albedo map.

But then a **map** again. A **map** refers to a two dimensional abstraction as in UV map. This would imply that you intend to use 2D textures, but your procedural rock needs 3D textures. As you can see, I'm in the dark what your desired output is.

Your last two images are useless.

[image]

To me they both show me a cg render of a rock. Nothing more. You explained, that you seek a procedural material and not a geometry creation method. This can't be explained by those two images, they convey identical/similiar information, remove them.

#### Be more specific

> for export in game engines

**What** game engine? Every game engine is different.

#### Keep it short**er**

- shrink images so they don't block the browser window
- don't repeat yourself
  *The first image of the Rock is what I want to recreate using Displacement, Albedo, and Normal Map

  I want the recreation of Displacement/Normal/Albedo map*
- don't say unnecessary information
  *Other tutorials/blogs/ Videos are not helping me because they are not the type of rock which I want to create.* [This is to vague to be useful.]

### Research

> a detailed study of a subject, especially in order to discover (new) information or reach a (new) understanding

The stackexchange faq isn't distinct in this point, but I would suggest showing the other users what **you** tried and then explain what didn't work. Everyone can do a web search of *procedural rock material*, but that doesn't count as research in my opinion.

I'd personally follow a tutorial with a procedural rock material. Then I'd have the material and assign it to a sphere as in your first example. Then explain in your question what's different from your result to what you want to achieve.

When people don't show me their own research with work/test heavy question I'm tempted to downvote, because it sounds like they want someone else to do their work.

*"Hey, we need a procedural rock material for our project but don't have time to study and create it, let's ask the folks at stackexchange.*

You will probably be able to do many of the steps of the answer you want. Give us your existing file/method and the answerer can make **few** and **specific** adjustments and explain them in depth. Creating a fully procedural rock material for free isn't an answer, its a job.

Research aside, here is how I'd word a question. I'm making some assumptions which aren't clear to me.

---

## Create tileable rock texture maps for export to Unity

I have created this rock shader.

[Image + Blend of shader]

I want to export it as a tileable texture to use with many objects in the Unity game engine. For that I need to create a 
- normal_map.png
- color_map.png
- glossy_map.png
- displacement.exr

How can I export the images from Blender?